# Connect to mongoDB Server which runs in a Docker container

Tags: database, mongodb, docker, connection, studio3t

I am trying to connect to MongoDB server which is running in a Docker container on my windows 10 machine. However when I try to connect to localhost:27017 I get an error. I wonder what am I missing?

[image]

[image]

I tried to connect to localhost:27017

Comment: First of all, can you show how did you run your container?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need to expose the port of your docker container so something like
`docker run -p 27017:27017 ...`

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/